# USB audio input is quiet (from XR18 mixing desk)

Tags: pulseaudio

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo laptop and am using a Behringer XR18 as an external sound card connected via USB.
All channels in both directions are present and audio out (laptop out to mixing desk in) is fine.
My problem is that audio in (mixing desk out to laptop in) is very very quiet.